# ThreadPoolExecutor: cancel tasks from invokeAll() when one task returns an error

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a threadpool executor doing the same operation for a list of keys coming in batches. so i am using invokeall() method to do the processing for a list of keys in a batch. the usecase is such that if any of the tasks in a batch returns an error, there is no point to continue processing for other keys. So

1. how can i cancel the tasks of the batch execution once a task has retuned an error.
2. but not effect the other batch of keys execution. ie the cancellation should be isolated per batch.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this can be done without a bit of customization. The simplest implementation I could come up with requires:

- a specialized Future implementation basically a subclass of [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) which overrides the setException() method in order to cancel all other tasks when a task throws an exception
- a specialized [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) implementation which overrides the invokeAll() to make use of the custom future

It goes like this:

for the custom future:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MyFutureTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> {
  private Callable<V> task;
  private Collection<Future<V>> allFutures;

  public MyFutureTask(Callable<V> task, Collection<Future<V>> allFutures) {
    super(task);
    this.task = task;
    this.allFutures = allFutures;
  }

  @Override
  protected void setException(Throwable t) {
    super.setException(t);
    synchronized(allFutures) {
      for (Future<V> future: allFutures) {
        if ((future != this) && !future.isDone()) {
          future.cancel(true);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for the custom thread pool:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MyThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  public MyThreadPool(int size) {
    super(size, size, 1L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
  }

  @Override
  public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException {
    List<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<>(tasks.size());
    for (Callable<T> callable: tasks) {
      futures.add(new MyFutureTask<>(callable, futures));
    }
    for (Future<T> future: futures) {
      execute((MyFutureTask<T>) future);
    }
    for (Future<T> future: futures) {
      try {
        future.get();
      } catch (ExecutionException|CancellationException e) {
        // ignore this exception
      }
    }
    return futures;
  }
}
```

code example to test it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TestThreadPool {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = null;
    try {
      int size = 10;
      executor = new MyThreadPool(size);
      List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
      int count=1;
      tasks.add(new MyCallable(count++, false));
      tasks.add(new MyCallable(count++, true));
      List<Future<String>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
      System.out.println("results:");
      for (int i=0; i<futures.size(); i++) {
        Future<String> f = futures.get(i);
        try {
          System.out.println(f.get());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
          System.out.println("CancellationException for task " + (i+1) +
            ": " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          System.out.println("ExecutionException for task " + (i+1) +
            ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (executor != null) executor.shutdownNow();
    }
  }

  public static class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private final int index;
    private final boolean simulateFailure;

    public MyCallable(int index, boolean simulateFailure) {
      this.index = index;
      this.simulateFailure = simulateFailure;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
      if (simulateFailure) {
        throw new Exception("task " + index + " simulated failure");
      }
      Thread.sleep(2000L);
      return "task " + index + " succesful";
    }
  }
}
```

and finally the outcome of executing the test, as displayed in the output console:

```
results:
CancellationException for task 1: null
ExecutionException for task 2: java.lang.Exception: task 2 simulated failure
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the reference of the `ExecutorService` to each task as bellow:

   ```
   ExecutorService eServ = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   Set<Callable<ReaderThread>> tasks = new HashSet<Callable<ReaderThread>>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
   {
       tasks.add(new ReaderThread(eServ));
   }

   List<Future<ReaderThread>> lt = eServ.invokeAll(tasks);
   ```
2. If task is error then call the `shutdownNow()` then it will stop all the tasks

   ```
   public ReaderThread call() throws Exception 
   {
       try     
       {
           for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
           {
               System.out.println("i="+i+"::"+Thread.currentThread());
               Thread.sleep(1000);

               if (i == 10 && Thread.currentThread().toString().equals("Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main]"))
               {
                   throw new Exception();
               }           
           }
       }
       catch ( Exception exc)
       {
           ex.shutdownNow();       
       }

       return this;
   }
   ```